# Yii2 remove index.php from url

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When I set the option in Yii to remove index.php from the URL I get a 404 error and this error in the error logs `File does not exist: /var/live/var`. In my browser I get this error `The requested URL /var/decat/frontend/web/index.php was not found on this server.` but the file is exactly in that location. What might explain that is that my document root is `/var/live` and decat is an alias as shown in the conf file.

This url works fine http://13.21.16.180/decat/index.php/site/login but when I remove index.php is when I get the error. I followed all the instructions to set it up in the conf file. I even tried through an .htaccess file. Here is the info from my conf file.

```
Alias /decat /var/decat/frontend/web

<Directory "/var/decat/frontend/web">
        # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
        RewriteEngine on
        # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
        RewriteRule . index.php 
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny 
        Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Comment: The config looks ok. Have you restarted the apache service?

Comment: I restarted it and now I get the new error that I posted in the question

Comment: If you say that your DocumentRoot is `/var/live` then I don't understand why you have Alias to `/var/decat` and not to `var/live`. Try `Alias /decat /var/live/frontend/web` and also `<Directory "/var/live/frontend/web">...`

Comment: Because I don't have the folder in the document root to enhance security, that's why I'm using an alias to access the only folder that should be accessible. The folder is in var/decat, it works fine with the index.php so the alias is working correctly

Comment: Try to add `RewriteBase /decat/` after `RewriteEngine on` (and restart apache)

Comment: that did it, please add your comment as an answer so I can assign the bounty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `RewriteBase /decat/` after `RewriteEngine on` and restart apache.

Answer (score 7):

You should set Url Manager component like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false, // Only considered when enablePrettyUrl is set to true
],
```

**Official docs:**

- [$enablePrettyUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$enablePrettyUrl-detail)
- [$showScriptName](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$showScriptName-detail)

Comment: That's what I have it set as, that gets rid of the index.php and that's when I get the error

Comment: @GauravParashar He mentioned error in the very beginning of the question.

Answer (score 5):

You should change .htaccess as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and urlManager rule as

```
 'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
    ],
```

I am using this in my app. and it workes.
my url shoes as **www.example.com/user/view?id=1**

Comment: After these confuguration in server also we need to enable mod_rewrite.

In terminal run these commands

`sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart`

Now go to “/etc/apache2/apache2.conf” open it your favorite editor and change "**AllowOverride none**" to "**AllowOverride All**" save your changes and you need to restart Apache again by above command.
File will be on readonly mode. So ensure the root login so add "su" command first

`su
vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
sudo service apache2 restart`

http://tutsnare.com/remove-index-php-from-url-in-yii2/

Answer (score 4):

**yii2 remove web from url**

1) Edit your config/web.php file with the following at the

```
<?php
use \yii\web\Request;

$baseUrl = str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

return [
    ...
    'components' => [
            'request' => [
                'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
     ],
      ...
    ]
]
?>
```

2) Add the following htaccess to root/web

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

3) Add the following htaccess to root folder where application is installed

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ web/$1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your Apache configuration that is wrong... You are telling it to only rewrite requests of a single character as I'm reading it?

I think it needs to be:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

But I can be wrong, not an `apache` specialist

Comment: I get this error with that `File does not exist: /var/decat/frontend/web/site`, it should be `web/index.php` not `site`, but this is the same error I was getting before restarting the apache service

Comment: I haven't used `site` anywhere in my answer, no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: You should open up your index.php file and put something like `die("here");` at the start of it (before anything is done). If that is outputted instead of the error your apache is configured correctly and passing thing to yii.

Comment: did that and I got the same thing

Comment: Means that it never gets to Yii at all and that it is a problem in your Apache configuration. Are you sure it's reading your configuration at all? You should probably thinker a bit with the rewrite settings. It's very hard to diagnose like this.

Comment: that configuration is what is detailed in the yii manual. When index.php is included in the URL it works