# Migrated website to new Host and need to change base URL

Tags: yii2, migration, host

So.. apologies beforehand if this is incredibly simple or if I'm explaining this poorly.

I've migrated my site over from EHost to Justhost.com and I can't for the life of me figure out why it keeps redirecting my url to the old pathway (eg. website.php?r=site/index)

I've completely deleted the FTP Account associated with the old site and removed all files in the directory.. so it should have no relation to the YII2 framework I used earlier (which is what used to create the URL IIRC [it's been a while]).

Hoping for an explanation for why this happening, but would greatly appreciate any tips to help me debug this as well.

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is. Do you mean that you expect `example.com` and are getting instead `example.com/index.php?r=site/index`? In that case you probably didn't configure pretty URL and/or forgot to add the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30586775/7450047

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm expecting.  The confusing part is that I shouldn't have any Yii2 at all right now (there are no Yii2 files on the new server) yet I'm still getting the same Yii2 based URL used from the last site.  

I've tried to change the .htaccess file in multiple file paths, but it's had no effect.

Comment: Then your problem must be in your DNS or in `apache` configuration. Because basically each request coming from the web first goes to your DNS (which might redirect), then it goes to your App Server (apache or nginx). Just after that it will hit your code (where it can get another redirect).